# SPFieldUserValue.User.Email giving an deleted email address on prod

Tags: spuser, ad

Am very new to SharePoint. I have got stuck into a strange issue.

On Prod server **SPFieldUserValue.User.Email** giving an email address which as been deleted. Actually, there were 2 users with the same name in 2 diff domains e.g. james@abc.com and james@def.com the james@def.com user was deleted. However, still, it is fetching james@def.com on Prod server. But when I debug on dev server it get's james@abc.com 
The AD is same for both servers.

Any help / hint is hugely appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the second user profile still exists in SharePoint , so to overcome this issue , In production server just try to remove the second user from `User Information List` by navigating to

```
http://yoursite/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0
```

Check the user and from `actions menu` selects `delete users from the site collection.`

[image]